# Secondary Click: Click but not tap with two fingers

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, multi-touch

On my Macbook Pro, I prefer the secondary click to be "Click with two fingers", but the closest option that exists in the Trackpad Preferences is "Click or tap with two fingers".

Is there any way for me to keep the behaviour that "click with two fingers" is secondary click, but make it so that "tap with two fingers" does nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you choose for clicking to be the only option (meaning, deselect the "tap to click" option underneath the 
secondary click" option), you should be allowed to only click with two fingers for the secondary click. That is one very simple, straight-forward way of solving your issue.

[image]