# Click (but not tap) with two fingers to activate secondary click while being able to tap with one finger

Tags: trackpad

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/243219/secondary-click-click-but-not-tap-with-two-fingers) doesn't solve the problem cause it deactivates a single finger tap.
Probably you guys are aware of some terminal magic here.
Many thanks!

Comment: It does it natively, no need to do anything

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem by using BetterTouchControl app; however it's paid